# Return value related to file content header

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an attachment uploading feature in my web app.

File can have type- `image/png` or `image/jpg` or `image/jpeg` or `application/pdf`

For images, I need to return Photo, for pdf Document.

Documents will be the only pdf, but images can be extended to images/ico, etc.

Now my code looks like this.

```
getAttachmentType(attachmentTypeHeader: string): string {
    if (
        attachmentTypeHeader === 'image/png' ||
        attachmentTypeHeader === 'image/jpg' ||
        attachmentTypeHeader === 'image/jpeg'
    ) {
        return 'Photo';
    }
    if (attachmentTypeHeader === 'application/pdf') {
        return 'Document';
    }
}
```

How I can make it check like `image/*`?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript strings have methods to test against only the start and end of a string: [String.prototype.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [String.prototype.endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith). The two methods each take a string, and check that it is equal to the start and end of their host string respectively.

Using this knowledge, you can reduce the `if` statement in your function `getAttachmentType` to test for `image/` only by replacing

```
if (
    attachmentTypeHeader === 'image/png' ||
    attachmentTypeHeader === 'image/jpg' ||
    attachmentTypeHeader === 'image/jpeg'
)
```

with

```
if (attachmentTypeHeader.startsWith('image/'))
```

Hope this helps. If you have any questions, I will do my best to answer them in the comments.